# Html.Grid Template, Html Code is not recognized

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Html.Grid, I've added a template in few column and these template is a combo with data and HTML code that's an image. But after building, the HTML code appears in text and I can read it in the page load in my browser, and I don't know why... Can you help me please?

Here is the code of my views:

```
@model MvcTools.Grid.GridModel<Suivi.View_OrgaRdv>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Grid";
}

@(Html.Grid<Suivi.OrgaRdv>()
.Title("rdv")
.DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.org_ID))
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns
               .Bound(c => c.org_Nom)
               .Title("Nom")
               .Width("200px")
               .HtmlAttributes("id","orgNom");                   


        columns
            .Bound(c => c.DataRv)
            .Title("rv " + DateTime.Today.Year)
            .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .Width("100px")
            .Template(p =>
                {
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                    if (p.DataRv>= ((p.DiffRv)))
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", p.DataRv, "<img src='...' />");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(p.NombreRdvN);
                    }

                    return sb.ToString();
                });
            //.HtmlAttributes("class","celT1", )
            //.HtmlAttributes("class", "celT2", );

        columns
            .Bound(c => c.DataDer)
            .Title("Dernier")
            .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .Width("100px")
            .Template(p =>
                {
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    if (p.DataDer<= p.first)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", String.Format("{0:d}", p.DataDer), "<img src='' />");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("{0}",String.Format("{0:d}",p.DataDer));
                    }                     
                 return sb;
                 //return sb.toString();
                }
            )
            ;


               }
))
.ToolBarPosition(Cci.Mvc.UI.ToolBarPosition.Top)
.Source(Model.Query)
.Sort(c => c.org_Nom) 
.Page(1)
.PageSize(30) 
.Pageable()
.DataSource(dataSourceBuilder => dataSourceBuilder.Ajax().Read("Grid", "RV"))
.ApplyDataSourceRequest(Model.DataSourceRequest)
.Render())
```

Thanks

Comment: use @html.raw() to decode that html appearing in text.

Comment: Yes i tried, but it did'nt work.

Comment: I just add:
`.HtmlEncode(false)` before the template and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I'm using `.HtmlEncode(false)`
    
`columns
    .Bound(c => c.DifferenceSaisie)
    .Title("Différence "+DateTime.Today.Year+" et "+( DateTime.Today.Year-   1))
    .Width("100px")
    .HtmlEncode(false)
    .Template(p=>
                {
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", p.DifferenceSaisie, Html.Raw("<img src=''/>"));
                    return sb;
                });`